# Windows 10 Machine Cannot Connect to Some Public Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I am on Windows 10, and there are some wifi my laptop can't connect but my iphone 7 can.

And I notice some weird stuffs on my laptop:
1. it has a DNS suffix (from the VPN at work but it is there even I am not running FortiClient).
2. it has 2 DNS entries from work (even I am not running FortiClient).

Here is the network info before my laptop connects to any wifi:

```
C:\Users\h>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-9UT1FIV
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : [my physical address]
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : [another physical address]
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

After my laptop connects to a "broken" wifi (working for my iphone):

```
C:\Users\h>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-9UT1FIV
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mywork.com

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : [another physical address]
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : [my physical address]
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.161.165.206(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.224.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, January 4, 2018 3:49:24 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, January 4, 2018 4:04:28 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.161.160.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.161.128.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.1.200.181
                                       172.1.208.81
                                       8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

This is the network info after I connect to my iphone (tethering and working):

```
C:\Users\h>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-9UT1FIV
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mywork.com

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : [another physical address]
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : [my physical address]
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, January 4, 2018 3:59:27 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, January 5, 2018 3:45:06 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.1.200.181
                                       172.1.208.81
                                       8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:18e3:5b70:4910:a696(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::18e3:5b70:4910:a696%10(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 268435456
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-8D-A3-00-98-83-89-25-3E-30
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

C:\Users\h>
```

I have a feeling that when it connects to a "broken" wifi, it tries to use the first DNS server at work (172.1.200.181) ONLY because when I tried to access the default gateway's IP (of the "broken" wifi) in the browser, it tried to redirect me to logon page (common for public wifi) with a domain name, and then it couldn't resolve the domain name and stop there.  If it used 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.8.4 (the 3rd and 4th entries) of DNS servers (google's), then it should have resolved the domain name correctly.

So my questions are:
1. is there a way to reorder the DNS entries in Windows 10?
2. is there a way to diagnose the issues further?  (as I really want to fix this, it is annoying that I can't use public wifi while on the road)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reorder DNS servers. Instead, delete and add to change priority. Command example posted [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5a1732db-ed89-4a87-8b6c-b784001853df/reorder-dns-entries-on-interface?forum=winservercore). However, I am unsure if valid for Win10.

> Adding a new one will push the others down the list. You can add and delete but can't reorder, you'll have to use add and delete to get things in the order you want.
>
> Delete command is:
>
> `netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsserver name="<ID>" address=<DNSIP>`

(You can set `address=all` to delete the whole list and start from scratch)

DNS solving should be top down. If in doubt run `nslookup`, although the information should still be the same.

Do WireShark captures to see if there is something else up. Do more digging before ruling out that DNS is the issue.

Comment: Please copy and paste in the exact solution from the link you posted. The contents of that linked discussion could change or be deleted. Also, it is not clear what you are suggesting is the actual answer. Be specific about how the problem can be solved.

Comment: @HackSlash thanks for checking, solution i'm sharing is for question 1 based on the link provided information would be:
Delete is:netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsserver name="<ID>" address=<DNSIP>

You can set address=all to delete the whole list and start from scratch.
Regarding question 2 is comments but not answer.

Comment: @DRP Welcome to [su]! You can use backticks (\`) to insert code or commands `inline`, even in comments. BTW, this is better as an answer than a comment, even if it's only a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have some funny DNS settings on your Wi-Fi adapter.

1. Go to **Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections**
2. Right click the Wi-Fi adapter you are using and select Properties.
3. Select IPv4 and click the Properties button
4. Click Advanced...
5. Click the DNS tab

It should look like this:

[image: Advanced DNS settings]

You might have to clear out the junk in there to get DNS working as expected but these settings might be required for your work VPN.

If you are using work provided equipment, check with your IT department before changing a bunch of settings. Connecting to strange Wi-Fi with your work laptop might be against corporate policy. Always use your work VPN to protect your connection when using a work device on strange Wi-Fi networks.